# Create Quadratic Equation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I Cant figure this out, its been so long since I've done math.

I need to create an equation from the following sequence:

[1000, 3000, 6000, 10000]

Comment: What have you done so far? Is there any background?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by an equation here, but the simplest pattern seems to be: Start with 0. Add 1 thousand. Add 2 thousand. Add 3 thousand. Add 4 thousand. Continue as far as desired. (You might find some use in looking up Triangular Numbers on Wikipedia.)

Comment: well Ive tried going back to old school books to find the following: Tn = a(n)(n) + b(n) + c.

And I know the pattern has a second difference of 1000. 

to find the nth term

Comment: You can also work this out by the method of undeterminate coefficients, starting from your $T_n$ equation: you know that $T_1=a+b+c=1000$, $T_2=4a+2b+c=3000$, and $T_3=9a+3b+c=6000$. Compute the 1st and 2nd order differences and you can solve for $a, b, c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "finite differences" applied to powers of integers.

Consider the sequence $1, 2, 3, 4, 5...$. Its "equation" can be written as $T_i=i$.

Take the differences of successive terms, $T_{i+1}-T_i$. This gives $1, 1, 1, 1...$ Because $(i+1)-i=1$. These differences are constant.

Now try the sequence of $T_i=i^2$: $1, 4, 9, 16, 25$... (the perfect squares).

The differences are $3, 5, 7, 9...$ because $T_{i+1}-T_i=(i+1)^2-i^2=i^2+2i+1-i^2=2i+1$. They are growing linearly. Take again the differences (these is called the second order differences), and you get the constant $2$.

In your case, the first order differences are $2000, 3000, 4000$, also growing linearly. The second order differences are the constant $1000$.

Since $1000=500\cdot2$, you can try the sequence $T_i=500\cdot i^2$: $500, 2000, 4500, 8000, 12500...$.

This is not (yet) the same as your original sequence, but it has a similar growth (second order difference is $500$).

Compare by subtracting the corresponding terms: $1000-500, 3000-2000, 6000-4500, 10000-8000=500, 1000, 1500, 2000$. Once again a linearly growing sequence, also with increment $500$.

This new sequence is obviously $T_i=500\cdot i$: $500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500...$

So the total must be $\color{blue}{T_i=500\cdot i^2+500\cdot i}$: $1000, 3000, 6000, 10000, 15000...$

Done.

Comment: Thank you! Thats it exactly. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You can make the method systematic. Find the order $n$ that turns your sequence into a constant, find the correction factor $f$ (knowing that 1st OD of $i$ is $1$, 2nd OD of $i^2$ is $2$, 3rd OD of $i^3$ is $3!=6$, 4th OD of $i^4$ is $4!=24$...) and subtract $T_i-f\cdot i^n$. You will get a new, simpler sequence to which you can apply the same procedure. This method will work whenever the sequence has a polynomial equation (if it has not, the differences will never turn to a constant).